# Is there a quick way to create a hyperlink to open microsoft office document in an existing email chain?

Tags: microsoft-office

I often find that I am working on a Microsoft Office document (spreadsheet, slideshow, word document, etc) while I have an email chain open in Outlook and I want to create a hyperlink in the email to the document that is open. What I do now is open Windows Explorer, navigate to the saved document and right-click drag into the email chain where I select "Create Hyperlink Here". Is there a way to accomplish this without having to open Windows Explorer and navigate to the containing folder? (Maybe something similar to the way proxy icons work on the Mac?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can configure the quick access toolbar to show the path and filename of the current file, like so:

[image]

Instructions to do this at http://www.howtogeek.com/161002/how-to-display-the-location-of-a-file-on-the-quick-access-toolbar-in-office-2013/. With that info it is a simple copy/paste in to the email.

Comment: This answers my original question but it would be nice if I could now find a way to attach the file to an existing email chain.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open Windows Explorer, but you still need to browse for that file.

Press "Ctrl+K" to open *Insert Hyperlink* window and browse for the file.

Comment: Getting rid of every click helps but I am really looking to eliminate the step of having to navigate to the document. I find myself thinking, "the computer already knows how to get to the file--why do I have to tell it again." :)

Answer (score 1):

In office 2010, I can navigate to the folder a bit faster using :  `File -> Recent -> Recent Places`

Hope that helps.